# How to find out if Rosmaster is running yet?

Tags: ros, rosmaster, publisher, topics, parameter-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to debug a node that is supposed to publish a "shutdown message" to a topic.  Since I am running rostests on my nodes, this message is supposed to get published fairly early after I launch my nodes.

Unfortunately, sometimes the message-sending happens and sometimes it doesn't.  I am even using the "latch" option on my publisher (so that a subscriber can still receive a message that was sent before the subscriber started).

My current suspicion is that the Rosmaster sometimes doesn't have time to initialize.  I've been hunting around for a way to check on the Master's status, but I can't seem to find it.  Is there a way to make sure the Rosmaster is running?

(as an addendum: I'm not looking for a terminal command.  I'm looking for some kind of code that would let my node know that rosmaster is reachable.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65685/how-to-find-out-if-rosmaster-is-running-yet?/) by [Toletum](https://answers.ros.org/users/5178/toletum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2013-06-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In `python` there's a way. See [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/61304/rospy-master-status/#65246).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-07-15**:
If the master did not start running, would the other nodes actually start? (I get a socket error when I try)..

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-07-15**:
@trinighost I think a node tries to connect Master upon booting, and fails if Master not running with specified URI. That's probably the error you're seeing.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-07-15**:
@trinighost and be sure not to ask new questions in comment area ;)

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-07-16**:
I was trying to clarify that this was a solution to the same problem.. because I wasn't clear on how the OP was able to avoid the error that I saw. I promise that I wasn't trying to ask a new question :)